# Access all MemoViews on a DataBand

Tags: delphi, fastreport

In Delphi I assign a TfrxUserDataSet to a report band:

```
var
  Band : TfrxDataBand;
begin
  Band := frxReport1.FindObject('MyBandName') as TfrxDataBand;
  Band.DataSet := frxUserDataSet1;
end;
```

After that I also need to assign the dataset to all MemoViews on that band.

```
var
  AMemo : TfrxMemoView;
begin
  AMemo:=Form1.frxReport1.FindObject('Memo3') as TfrxMemoView;
  AMemo.DataSet:=ABand.DataSet;
  //... and so forth, for all MemoViews on the report band
end;
```

but is there a way to iterate over all memoviews on a databand without knowing their names?
I suppose I could read the report's .FR3 file and use its structured specification, but I would prefer not to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate the **ContainerObjects** collection to access child components. For example:

```
var
  I: Integer;
  Band: TfrxDataBand;
  Control: TfrxComponent;
begin
  Band := frxReport1.FindObject('MyBandName') as TfrxDataBand;

  for I := 0 to Band.ContainerObjects.Count - 1 do
  begin
    Control := Band.ContainerObjects[I];
    if Control is TfrxMemoView then
    begin
      TfrxMemoView(Control).DataSet := Band.DataSet;
      ...
    end;
  end;
end;
```